# amTimeAgo angular-moment UTC Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-template, angular-moment

I am trying to achieve making a calculation of time based on:

```
MY LOCAL TIME (converted to utc) - PUBLICATION TIME FROM DATABASE (already in UTC) = DIFFERENCE IN SECONDS
```

Angular-moment library offers a good module for making these calculations on the HTML component. I am using the amTimeAgo pipe, however, the calculation appears to be correct for subtracting mytime - publication time from database, however it is not converting mytime (my actual local time) to UTC format.

Is there a way that I can manually edit the javascript to make this calculation of where ever it is pulling the local time from and convert it to UTC always ?

**This is my front end HTML code:**

```
<time>{{(i['pubDate']) | amTimeAgo }}</time>
```

Comment: I already answered to this question by you.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the answer was not working for me, and i am changing my direction now with which pipe to use @dAxx_

Comment: you can open your dev tools right now F12, type: var a = new Date(); and then, var b = a.toUTCString(); and then type b, You will get the current time in UTC. This is how you do it. nothing special is necessary.

Comment: so in which part of my HTML listed above should I include variable b, can you type that out ?

Comment: I think if I alter the angular-moment.js file, which contains the now(), then it will make the calculations in UTC time.